# Importing contact only imports first contact number in contact list

Tags: java, android, contacts

This code seems fine. I have researched in many Websites, but when I run the code, only the first number in contact list comes to the text view. But I want desired contact number to be shown in the edit text view.

```
private void importContact() {

    Intent importContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    importContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(importContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT):

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Uri contactData = data.getData();
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                    null, null);
            cursor.moveToNext();
                String name = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                destinationPhoneNumber = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                //
                enterPhoneNumber.setText(destinationPhoneNumber);
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        name + " has number " + destinationPhoneNumber,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want all numbers of a particular contact?

Comment: did you find the ans useful?

Comment: @MohammedAli if there are multiple numbers then let the user choose it. I'm trying for single number only ...

Comment: So what is you question? I showed you a way to get all numbers of a particular contact...

Comment: @MohammedAli can i get more help on this topic ... the problem is given on the comment of u answer

Comment: what problem.. if you have another question then ask another on stackoverflow.. and post me the link here.

Comment: @MohammedAli the link of next question is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357111/failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-request-1-result-1-data-intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query like this to get all the numbers of a particular contact:

```
String id = cur.getString(cur
  .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
String name = cur
  .getString(cur
    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

image_uri = cur
  .getString(cur
    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
if (Integer
  .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
 //System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

 // NOW query all numbers of that particulat contact using contact_Id
 Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
   null,
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
     + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
 // you can store phone in a arrayList
  phone = pCur
    .getString(pCur
      .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
  //System.out.println("phone" + phone);
 }
 pCur.close();
 }
```

Comment: Cursor pCur = cr.query , this line shows the error . (cr cannot be resolved )

Comment: ok no error but when i run this application and choose a contact , it causes a error . and application crashes . After clicking to certain contact

Comment: then see the error in your code... the above code is tested.

Comment: the error in log cat is : "Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup…}}"

Comment: ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER returns -1 for me, any suggestion?