# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup…}}

Tags: android, contacts, onactivityresult

Error while i choose a contact from the contact list .
Any help from you will be nice ... 
Here is the code for receiving number from contact and showing it in edit text view :

private void importContact() {

```
    Intent importContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    importContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(importContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT):

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Uri contactData = data.getData();
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (Integer
                    .parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                // System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                // NOW query all numbers of that particulat contact using
                // contact_Id
                Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // you can store phone in a arrayList
                    destinationPhoneNumber = pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    //
                    enterPhoneNumber.setText(destinationPhoneNumber);
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            name + " has number " + destinationPhoneNumber,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the log cat error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0i473.3217i217333/217328 (has extras) }} to activity {np.com.rsubedi.balancetransfer/np.com.rsubedi.balancetransfer.BTmain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at np.com.rsubedi.balancetransfer.BTmain.onActivityResult(BTmain.java:220)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post your error

Comment: @Amsheer look at the Title of this question , thats the error

Comment: `cursor` is not initialized, where are you querying the contacts DB?

Comment: Im just trying to show the number in TextView ...

Comment: Error starts at `BTmain.java:220` line 220. what is at line 220?

Comment: @MohammedAli this is at line 220: if (Integer
      .parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66403/discussion-between-rahul-subedi-and-mohammed-ali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first query the Contacts DB like this:

```
ContentResolver resolvr = getContentResolver();  
Cursor cursor = resolvr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

The resultSet is in `cursor`.